# php does nothing when getting ajax POST request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple php site that displays a showreel of articles stored in my database. I want to be able to click onto the article title `<h1 class="article-title">` and display only that article.

I thought the easiest way to do this, was by checking for a post request when the site loads. If it has a request with the article title, It would display only that article, if not, it displays the whole feed.

Upon clicking on the header, I can see the POST request in my console, but nothing happens, and I can't figure out why. I don't even know if my data is posted correctly.

First time that I'm doing something like this, so help is appreciated.

I've also changed the db setting to blank in the code I pasted. Thanks for the help

```
<?php
$page_title = "Articles";
include('inc/header.php');

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
?>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE title = " . $_POST;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
                "<h1 class='article-title'>" . $row["title"] . "</h1>" 
                . "<h2>" . date("j. F, Y", strtotime($row['post_date'])) . "</h2>" 
                . "<p>" . nl2br($row["extract"]) . "</p><hr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
else {
    //make article newsfeed

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
                "<h1 class='article-title'>" . $row["title"] . "</h1>" 
                . "<h2>" . date("j. F, Y", strtotime($row['post_date'])) . "</h2>" 
                . "<p>" . nl2br($row["extract"]) . "</p><hr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?> 
<?php
include('inc/footer.php');
?>
<script>
    $( ".article-title" ).click(
        function() {
            var title = $(this).text();

            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
            }

            xhr.open('POST', 'articles.php');
            xhr.send(title);
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: is your `articles.php` at right path, and And near to the console., in the `Networks` can you able to see the response ?

Comment: I can't see a response, only the POST request. You can see it in action [here](http://topdeckandwreck.com/PTC-Testers/articles.php) . Is the problem that the .php page is not reloading when receiving the POST request?

Comment: Php file don't need to reload while receiving the post request. I guess the code you use to send the request has some error. May i help  you with clean jquery ?

Comment: yes ofc, like I said first time I'm doing something with php so I just figure the error was there. You can build the jQuery from scratch or whatever you mean by clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simple jquery call to external page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $( ".article-title" ).click(function(){
           var title = $(this).text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "articles.php",
                 data: { 
                'title': title, 
            },
                success : function(data)
                {
                console.log(data);
                $("#content").html(data);
                }
            },"json");
        });
</script>
```

Here for the test purpose you echo the value that you got

i.e., `echo $_POST['title'];`

And in your console you should get the one what you have in the `title`

If that is ok you can have a div with id `result` to get those values,

Comment: this returns an error on the 2nd line `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

Comment: Sorry, i left a syntax mistake.. Now i have updated the answer. Can you check it with this

Comment: with only `echo $_POST['title'];` in my php function, the ajax function now console.logs the whole thing (including the rest of the php code). So if I do .html on my content div, I get a page inside a page. Guess I just need to figure out how to access only the query results? TBH this seems a very messy way to do it

Comment: It was really easy, and never worry :) just try with this `var title = "test"` and see whether it displays test in the result div ?

Comment: got it working now. I'll just put the sql query in a separate .php file and call it with ajax. There are a few minor mistakes in your code mainly the file name should be articles.php and the id is #content, not #result. Edit those out and I'll accept the anwser. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` in php is an array, so this line is incorrect:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE title = " . $_POST;`

A few suggestions:

It's always nice during debugging to see what's actually in the $_POST array, try dumping the entire array to the screen with `print_r($_POST);`.

Look up how to do bind parameters when doing your mysqli query and bind the title to your query instead of using `.` to do string concatenation. As it is it is vulnerable to sql injection.

When you setup your `title` parameter in the JS, try making it a name value pair: `var title = 'title=' + $(this).text();`. Then in php the title would be in `$_POST['title']`

Comment: I tried running `print_r($_POST);` under `($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`, and still nothing happens (I commented the rest of the if statement out). I guess the problem is with the ajax function? Or is the if clause wrong?